# Xcode 4.5.2: cannot inspect object properties in debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode4.5

When I'm debugging in Xcode 4.5.2 and I open the disclosure triangle for an object in the inspector, I often don't see its properties.  For example, in the screenshot below, I'm trying to inspect the UILabel, but the 'text' and other properties of UILabel don't appear.

[image]

On the other hand, if I were to subclass the UILabel (e.g. MyUILabel) and create a custom property (e.g. customText), that property will show up fine in the inspector:

[image]

Any idea why 'text' and other UILabel properties don't appear for me? Is this a setting that I need to turn on?

Comment: No, it's probably a bug.

Comment: I never use that part of the debugger because I don't really trust it, so just use the console part e.g. `po [label text]`. `po` means `print object` - then it's just a case of executing things

Comment: @trojanfoe, I think you're right. If you submit an answer, I'll give you credit for it and hopefully this will serve as an artifact for others who encounter the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrated from a comment to an answer (not that it's much of one):

**No, it's probably a bug**